# VBA USER FORM error 6 work around

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a bunch of Combo boxes that has a option for Yes, No or N/A
Then I Have a Command button that that runs a calculation then moves to the next page

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim a As Long, b As Long

a = IIf(Cbx1_1.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_2.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) +_
IIf(Cbx1_3.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_4.Value = "Yes", 1, 0)

b = 4 - IIf(Cbx1_1.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(Cbx1_2.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)_
- IIf(Cbx1_3.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(Cbx1_4.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)
OUTBX1.Text = Format(a / b, "00.00%")
MultiPage1.Value = 1
End Sub
```

Now the Only Problem that I am experiencing now is that if all the boxes are check as "N/A" then I get the 0/0 problem (Error 6 : Overflow)

I know that with Excel I would have used an ERRORIF formula to solve this. Is there a way that I can tell VBA that if:

```
=ERRORIF (b=0) then MultiPage1.Value = 1 else 
    OUTBX1.Text = Format(a / b, "00.00%")
```

Comment: You can try using [Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-iferror-method-excel) or some [Error Handling](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Comment: I am confused. Why don't you use a simple `IF`-statement?

Comment: @FunThomas; yeah solution here is simple. Just use: `IF a = 0 or b = 0 then Else multipage1.value.... `

Comment: what does the result of your calculation represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for you help the final answer to this is coded as following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim a As Long, b As Long

a = IIf(Cbx1_1.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_2.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_3.Value = "Yes", 1, 0) + IIf(Cbx1_4.Value = "Yes", 1, 0)
b = 4 - IIf(Cbx1_1.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(Cbx1_2.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(Cbx1_3.Value = "N/A", 1, 0) - IIf(Cbx1_4.Value = "N/A", 1, 0)

If b = 0 Then
MultiPage1.Value = 1

Else
OUTBX1.Text = Format(a / b, "00.00%")
MultiPage1.Value = 1
End If
End Sub
```